# Is There a Way to Consolidate This Code More?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code works fine but it feels really inefficient since every time I add a new section, I have to make another script and change all the Id's. It's not a big deal, but it just feels really bloated.

I'm not really sure what to try as I'm recently new to coding. Here's what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Update Log</title>
    <style>
        p {
            display: none;
        }
        #textHide {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: blue;
            display: none;
        }
        #textHide1 {
            text-decoration: underline;
            color: blue;
            display: none;
        }
        span {
            border: 1px black solid;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }
        header {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Update Log</h1>
    </header>
    <span title="Version 1 Updates">
        <div onclick="paraDrop()" style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 2px;">Version 1</div><div style="display: inline-block;" id="rotate" onclick="paraDrop()"> > </div>
    </span>
    <p id="dropdown">
        hello
    </p>
        <div onclick="paraUp()" id="textHide">
            Hide Text
        </div>
    <script>
        function paraDrop() {
            let text = document.getElementById('dropdown');
            text.style.display = "block";
            let textTwo = document.getElementById('textHide');
            textTwo.style.display = "block";
            let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
            rotate.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        }
        function paraUp() {
            let text = document.getElementById('dropdown');
            text.style.display = "none";
            let textTwo = document.getElementById('textHide');
            textTwo.style.display = "none";
            let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate');
            rotate.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
        }
    </script>
    <br>
    <br>
     <span title="Version 2 Updates">
        <div onclick="paraDrop1()" style="display: inline-block; padding-right: 2px;">Version 2</div><div style="display: inline-block;" id="rotate1" onclick="paraDrop1()"> > </div>
    </span>
    <p id="dropdown1">
        hello
    </p>
        <div onclick="paraUp1()" id="textHide1">
            Hide Text
        </div>
        <script>
            function paraDrop1() {
                let text = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
                text.style.display = "block";
                let textTwo = document.getElementById('textHide1');
                textTwo.style.display = "block";
                let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate1');
                rotate.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
            }
            function paraUp1() {
                let text = document.getElementById('dropdown1');
                text.style.display = "none";
                let textTwo = document.getElementById('textHide1');
                textTwo.style.display = "none";
                let rotate = document.getElementById('rotate1');
                rotate.style.transform = "rotate(360deg)";
            }
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have two functions to make the paragraphs appear and disappear. I just want to know if there's a way to streamline the js or to make a simpler drop-down that I can add to over time.

Comment: Sure, have a look at [MDN: <details>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details). With that tag you can get rid of the JS entirely. And when `#textHide` and `#textHide1` have the same CSS you can use `#textHide, #textHide1 { same code }`

Comment: But, SO isn't used for asking advice. Just to help to find errors in your code. People will vote to close the question, no doubt.

Comment: If your code works fine, then there [isn't really anything for Stackoverflow to do](/help/on-topic). If you need code review, including "how to do what you're already doing, better" then https://codereview.stackexchange.com is the (potentially) right place instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS classes instead of IDs to make the same classes and functions work for multiple options.

For example, like so:

```js
function paraDrop(el) {
  el.parentElement.classList.add('open');
}

function paraUp(el) {
  el.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove('open');
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 2px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-size: 14pt;
}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .content {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown.open .arrow {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.dropdown.open .content {
  display: block;
}

.textHide {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Update Log</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Update Log</h1>
  </header>
  <div title="Version 1 Updates">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="label" onclick="paraDrop(this)">Version 1 <span class="arrow"> > </span></div>
      <div class="content">
        hello
        <div onclick="paraUp(this)" class="textHide">Hide Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div title="Version 2 Updates">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="label" onclick="paraDrop(this)">Version 2 <span class="arrow"> > </span></div>
      <div class="content">
        hello
        <div onclick="paraUp(this)" class="textHide">Hide Text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if this helps.